# Getting error call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently i install wordpress in local system with jupitex theme . But after add sales price value i am getting below error in "class-wp-hook.php" file.

```
"call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'jupiterx_wc_product_page_custom_sale_badge' not found or invalid function name in";
```

frondend working fine . but in elementor backend i am getting this error.[image]

If anyone have idea then let me know what is exact issue.

Comment: It is usually caused by a filter or an action not properly declared. this function is not properly declared 'jupiterx_wc_product_page_custom_sale_badge'.

Comment: @Shaikh Aejaz Ahmed, so how should resolve these because i just import jupiterx theme. Actually any idea

Answer (score 0):

I checked the theme code the issue is with the theme. Actually they are not passing any parameters in this filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'jupiterx_wc_product_page_custom_sale_badge' );
```

But on woocommerce.php template they have added $output as function parameter which doesn't exist

```
function jupiterx_wc_product_page_custom_sale_badge( $output ) {
    $output = str_replace( 'onsale', 'onsale jupiterx-sale-badge', $output );

    return $output;
}
```

You can ask the theme developer to resolve the issue because even if i resolve the issue it will be gone once you update the theme.

Reinstall theme to the latest version & check as well